# How to Build a package with a mix of .java and .class in it in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, compilation

I laid hand on package which only partly contains out of 3 main .java classes and the rest is already precompiled in .class files.
When I try to compile it IntelliJ IDEA says it can’t find the definitions, although they are clearly there.
What should I do?

```
    ❯ tree
    .
    ├── cryptoman.iml
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   └── main
    │       ├── java (marked as sources)
    │       │   └── kanni
    │       │       └── grand
    │       │           ├── Main.java
    │       │           ├── Smthing1.java
    │       │           ├── Smthing2.java
    │       │           ├── ...
    │       │           ├── SendInChanelF.class
    │       │           ├── SendMessage.class
    │       │           ├── dataUsl.class
    │       │           ├── dataVar.class
    │       │           ├── db.class
    │       │           ├── s40data.class
    │       │           └── wAlgo.class
    │       └── resources (marked as resources)
    │           ├── ...
    │           └── ...
    └── target
    7 directories, 27 files
```

Editing as it is I have 2 problems.

1) In Main.java class IDE yells 'Cannot resolve symbol' at e.g.
`static SendInChanelF si1;`.
2) Trying to compile it says 'java: cannot find symbol' `SendInChanelF`

Ok. having searched the forum I tryed to put .class files in a diferrent folder and mark it as a dependancy 
`File -> Project Structure -> modules -> Dependencies -> Add -> JARS or Directory -> Choose the directory`

1) Now in Main.java class IDE resolves SendInChanelF.
2) But compiler is still refusing to compile.

Tried to invalidate Cache/Restart. Didn't help =)
To prevent your dislikes, sadly I can't use the source code.

Comment: Put your class files inside a jar. Install that jar in your Maven repo. Use it like any other dependency in your Maven project. But seriously? .class files, without the sources, and I guess also without any docuentation? I would never use that.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can't use the full source =( Is it possible to reuse those classes without maven?

Comment: Well, your build is based on Maven. So you'd better use a solution that works with Maven.

Comment: Methods and classes in those compiled classes are partly privat. Can't reuse them =( So only one option for me to work with them as if my classes are a part of that library. Am I wrong? Could you please tell me what other options do I have? Regardless whether they are conventional or not. Thank you!

Comment: What is the compiler error that you get? Can you share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by decompiling the sources. Closed. Thank you!